# Replace all occurrences but first of a repeating string in a column using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a column, in a pandas dataframe, in which sometimes there is a repeating string:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | hello |
| 2 | bye |
| 3 | hello |
| 4 | morning |
| 5 | night |
| 6 | hello |

Would I would like to do is to modify all but the first occurence of "hello" in "hello again". So the first occurence of hello remains the same.

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | hello |
| 2 | bye |
| 3 | hello again |
| 4 | morning |
| 5 | night |
| 6 | hello again |

Comment: It would be nice to see your train of thought

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find the indices of the rows containing `"hello"` and then modify all but the first occurrence using [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
   ...:                         'col2': ['hello', 'bye', 'hello', 'morning', 'night', 'hello']})
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   col1     col2
0     1    hello
1     2      bye
2     3    hello
3     4  morning
4     5    night
5     6    hello
In [4]: hello_indices = df.index[df['col2'] == 'hello']
In [5]: hello_indices
Out[5]: Int64Index([0, 2, 5], dtype='int64')
In [6]: df.loc[hello_indices[1:],'col2'] = 'hello again'
In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
   col1         col2
0     1        hello
1     2          bye
2     3  hello again
3     4      morning
4     5        night
5     6  hello again
```

Comment: @OP please un-accept my answer :( I think this is not how you are supposed to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.split(expand=True)[0]
```

`split()` by default split at space, and the expand=true creates two variables instead of two lists